# How to identify inputs for a diffusion model?

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface, stable-diffusion

I'm calling a Stable Diffusion in-painting model with the following code, however I know there are more parameters available in the model pipeline. How do I identify all the available parameters in [this stable diffusion in-painting model?](https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-inpainting)

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline

pipe = StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "runwayml/stable-diffusion-inpainting",
    revision="fp16",
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
)
prompt = "Face of a yellow cat, high resolution, sitting on a park bench"
#image and mask_image should be PIL images.
#The mask structure is white for inpainting and black for keeping as is
image = pipe(prompt=prompt, image=image, mask_image=mask_image).images[0]
image.save("./yellow_cat_on_park_bench.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the official list here: https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/v0.11.0/en/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion#diffusers.StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline

I guess the inputs are based on `StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline` parameters